# Is there a way for the python interpreative console to import my entire app at one time?

Tags: python, flask

Is there some sort of method or resource I can reference that would allow me to import my entire application into the python interpreter?

For example when I run `python` to do some flask-sql queries I have to do this EVERYTIME I exit:

```
python
import project
from project import app,db, etc etc
from project.models import Model, Model,
 goes on and on......
```

How can I avoid doing that to bypass the repetiveness? Coming from Rails, its so nice to just run `rails c` and have everything loaded for you.

Comment: Just create a python [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) or a module importing whole project namespaces.

Comment: You can use "flask shell"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have Python execute a file on interactive startup by setting the environmental variable `PYTHONSTARTUP`:

```
$ cat file.py 
print 'These definitions are executed before the REPL'
pi = 3.14
$ PYTHONSTARTUP=file.py python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 21 2013, 07:25:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
These definitions are executed before the REPL
>>> pi
3.14
>>>
```

It's right there at the bottom of `python --help`.

Comment: This was a huge help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ipython`, which is much nicer, with a script to set up your environment.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# appshell.py

import project
import somethingelse

import IPython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # see for notes on the arguments https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8918#issuecomment-149918372    
    IPython.embed(module=sys.modules['__main__'], user_ns=sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__)
```

Then invoke it with ./appshell.py

This has the advantage over `PYTHONSTARTUP` in that it can easily be committed to your repository, and doesn't need the calling environment to be configured. That said, you could make a bash script which configures `PYTHONSTARTUP` and then runs python/ipython

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONSTARTUP='...'
ipython
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed flask tag... Try using flask-script

```
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell
from myapp import app
from mymodule import module

manager = Manager(app)

def make_shell_context():
    return dict(module=module)


manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=make_shell_context)), 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

./manage.py shell will get you into python shell and mymodule will be already imported

Answer (score 1):

Try [**konch**](https://github.com/sloria/konch). From the docs:

- Automatically import any object upon startup
- List item
- Simple, per-project configuration in a single file (it's just Python code)
- No external dependencies
- Uses IPython, BPython, or ptpython if available, and falls back to built-in interpreter
- Automatically load IPython extensions
- Can have multiple configurations per project using named configs

There is a also a **Flask** extension for it: [**flask-konch**](https://github.com/sloria/flask-konch)

Answer (score 1):

Another lightweight option offered by the standard Python REPL and alternate REPLs (`bpython`, `ptython`) is passing the `-i` flag:

```sh
$ cat file.py
print('These definitions are executed before the REPL')

$ python -i file.py
These definitions are executed before the REPL
>>>

$ bpython -i file.py
These definitions are executed before the REPL
bpython version 0.17.1 on top of Python 3.6.1 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
>>>
```